# how to restrict order place if virtual product in cart with another product type magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3.4, onestepcheckout, place-order, virtual-products, restriction

I want to restrict order place on the checkout page if the virtual product in cart with another product type like Simple, Configurable, etc.

Users can place the order when either virtual product in cart or other product_type(Simple, configurable) products in the cart.

if both type products in the cart then the order will not be placed.